# Countdowntimer play sound when half of time is left

Tags: java, android, audio, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer which is 10 seconds long. I want to play a sound when half of the time is past on the timer. I can play sound but the problem is the audio is played twice.

Think that this is the sound I want to play: "Hi how are you."

It plays like this: "Hi Hi how are you.".

The playAudio() plays correct when it is not inside the onTick() method. It has something with the if(seconds == 5). I don't know what.

```
 public class RestCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public RestCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if(txtRestTime != null){
            if(finishSound != 0){
                sp.play(finishSound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            displayImage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(txtRestTime != null){
            long seconds = (millisUntilFinished+1000) / 1000;
            txtRestTime.setText("" + seconds);
            if(seconds == 5){
                playAudio(audio);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should post the code for your playAudio method.

Comment: The playAudio() plays correct when it is not inside the onTick() method. It has something with the if(seconds == 5). I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some logging, and see if your onTick millisUntilFinished is being called more often than you think. It's possible that it's being called e.g. at 5 seconds and at 5.5 seconds, both of which would generate a "seconds" variable of 5. You might either want to tweak the interval you're using, or else save a boolean soundPlayed and don't play again if it's set.

Answer (score 1):

Because my CountDownTimer was initialized like this I got the problem.

restCountDownTimer = new RestCountDownTimer(30000, 500);

If my interval would be 1000 I would not get the problem.

This is how I solved it. I created a boolean state variable to check if the sound is played once or not. If the sound is played then skip it next time.

```
public class RestCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    private boolean stateAudio = false;

public RestCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
    super(startTime, interval);
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    if(txtRestTime != null){
        if(finishSound != 0){
            sp.play(finishSound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            stateAudio = false;
        }
        displayImage();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    if(txtRestTime != null){
        long seconds = (millisUntilFinished+1000) / 1000;
        txtRestTime.setText("" + seconds);
        if((seconds == 5) && (stateAudio == false)){
            playAudio(audio);
            stateAudio = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}